# "ValueError with / in variable name when using optimizer.apply_gradients in TensorFlow 2.xx"

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm encountering a ValueError when trying to apply gradients using TensorFlow 2.xx's optimizer.apply_gradients method during the training of a BERT model. The error message is as follows:

```
ValueError: Argument `name` must be a string and cannot contain character `/`. Received: name=tf_bert_for_token_classification/bert/embeddings/word_embeddings/weight_0_momentum
```

This error occurs specifically at the line of code where gradients are being applied:

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

Upon inspecting the clipped_gradients variable, I noticed it contains variable names with the character /, for example:

```
Variable: tf_bert_for_token_classification/bert/embeddings/word_embeddings/weight:0
```

I understand that TensorFlow variable names often include / to indicate hierarchical structures within models, and such naming conventions have not caused issues in other contexts. My questions are:

Is this error indicative of a bug in TensorFlow version 2.xx, or am I missing something in how gradients should be applied when working with models like BERT?
How can I work around this issue to ensure gradients are applied correctly without causing a ValueError due to the presence of / in variable names?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

"I am expecting the optimizer.apply_gradients method to successfully apply the calculated gradients to the trainable variables of my BERT model without raising a ValueError due to the presence of the / character in the variable names. Since variable names containing / are common in TensorFlow to reflect the hierarchical structure of models, I was not anticipating this to cause an issue. My goal is to perform a standard training step where gradients calculated from the loss function are applied to update the model's weights, consistent with typical practices in training deep learning models with TensorFlow."